# I have a question about Photoshop (The program). Is it on topic?

Tags: discussion

I'm having a problem with photoshop 19.1 and scaling in Windows. Photoshop is a photographers tool but the question isn't necessarily just relevant to photography.

Is it on topic here?

Answer (score 2):

If it's not photography-specific, and it doesn't appear to be, I'd suggest superuser or graphic design.

Answer (score 2):

On the other hand, if your specific problem involves displaying photos using Photoshop on a Windows based computer, it might be.

Comment: So just start the question I edit photos in photoshop? How can I fix this weird DPI scaling issue affecting toolbars?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to say I think it would be.  If you are trying to use Photoshop to accomplish photo manipulation and are having a problem with the tool.  Trying to figure out how to fix that tooling problem could be on topic.  It's borderline, but it sounds like it probably falls within what I would consider to be in-bounds for the topic.

Put another way, it is a technical question, but it's a technical question about how to get a photo tool for a photo purpose working correctly.

Clearly it is borderline though given that there is disagreement even between the moderators on if it fits.  I think it would probably be left to a community vote for closure if you posted it.  Personally, I wouldn't discourage trying (having a question get closed is really not a big deal), but you also might get a quicker or better answer on SuperUser.

Comment: Do we have someone with moddy powers able to move it over to superuser if needs be?

Comment: Yes, as long as we move it within the first few weeks (I forget the exact cutoff, it might even be a few months).  Eventually posts stop being eligible for migration, but diamond moderators are able to move a question to any site in the network as long as it isn't past the cutoff.